# Sveltekit store.set is not a function

Tags: javascript, svelte, sveltekit

I wan't my each loop to act reactive when i remove one element from $page.form.errors. However for that I would need to reassign it like $page = $page. But if i do this then i get this error store.set is not a function:
[image]

So i check if there are any errors in $page.form.errors and if there are i render a toast.If i close all i want the #if to not render the toastContainer, only if there are some new errors.

```
{#if $page.form?.errors}
  <div id="toastContainer" class="toast toast-top toast-center w-4/12">
    {#each $page.form.errors as error, i}
      <div id="error{i}" class="alert alert-error">
        <div>
          <span>{error}</span>
        </div>
        <button
          class="btn btn-ghost"
          on:click={() => {
            $page.form.errors.splice(i, 1);
            console.log($page.form.errors);

            document.getElementById("error" + i)?.remove();
            // toastContainerEmpty();
          }}>X</button
        >
      </div>
    {/each}
  </div>
{/if}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could store the errors locally, then if the server invalidates, it will update and the local variable will be mutable:

```js
$: errors = $page.form?.errors;
```

(Use `errors` everywhere)

Comment: i have a follow up question. How would i then delete the element from $page.form?.errors

Comment: You would delete it from `errors`, the form store should not change until a form action is invoked.